# Stop Loss is not being calculated right

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

The system has a 1:2 Risk:reward ratio.
It sets the stop to the recent high for shorts and recent low for longs.
I implemented a minimum StopLoss distance of 0.075%.

FOR SHORTS (WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO):

If the recent high is lower than the entry price plus the minimum stop distance then the minimum stop is used. If the recent high is higher than the entry price plus the minimum stop distance than the recent high is used.

PROBLEM(WHAT IS HAPPENING):

Going over past positions this is not being followed, instead of using the highest high of the last 5 candles it is using a random amount with no pattern I could find or minimum stop loss when it shouldn't be.

THE PICTURES ATTACHED SHOW EACTLY WHAT IM TRYING TO CONVEY

MY CODE:

```
MinStopLong = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.00075)
MinStopShort = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + 0.00075)
StopLossLong = ta.lowest(low,5)
StopLossShort = ta.highest(high,5)
if MinStopLong < StopLossLong
    StopLossLong := MinStopLong
if MinStopShort > StopLossShort
    StopLossShort := MinStopShort

//Take Profit-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TakeProfitLong = strategy.position_avg_price + (2 * (strategy.position_avg_price -    StopLossLong))
TakeProfitShort = strategy.position_avg_price - (2 *(StopLossShort - strategy.position_avg_price))


//Strategy Exit------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if strategy.position_size>0
    strategy.exit(id='close', stop=StopLossLong, limit=TakeProfitLong) 
if strategy.position_size<0
    strategy.exit(id='close', stop=StopLossShort, limit=TakeProfitShort)
```

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfFVT.png)

Comment: Can you share the complete code as we can help you ?

Comment: @G.Lebret what other code do you need to answer this question as the full script is 150 lines, should i send the entire thing? Or should i send a specified part?

Comment: Yes you should paste the complete code, it will be easier to help.